# Javascript For Final Expression does not allow complex statements. Why?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, expression

Reasons aside, I've discovered the following:

```
var lines = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"], i = 0, line;

for (line[i]; i < lines.length; line = lines[i++]) {
     console.log(line); //Outputs "Line 1" three times
}

for (line[i]; i < lines.length; i++, line = lines[i]) {
     console.log(line); //Outputs "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"
}
```

The only difference is separating out the i++ in the final-expression statement into two statements separated by commas (who thought of that syntax, BTW?! Shouldn't multiple statements be separated by semi-colons and wrapped in {}, like we use everywhere else? I digress...) So what gives Javascript? Is line=lines[i++] too complicated for you while your wrapping around that loop?

And before anyone asks why I can't just put the line=lines[i] inside, at the top of the loop: Because the first example is just elegant. It keeps things separated.

So my question stands: Why, Javascript, why?

Comment: What kind of `for` loop is this?

Comment: both loops fail to run with `line is undefined`

Comment: Sometimes its not the Language but how you use it make your feel *WTF...*

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't run.

The beginning of each for loop

```
 for (line[i];
```

makes no sense.

Maybe you meant

```
 for (line = lines[i];
```

?

```js
var lines = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"], i = 0, line;

for (line = lines[i]; i < lines.length; line = lines[i++]) {
     console.log(line); //Outputs "Line 1" three times
}

i = 0;
for (line = lines[i]; i < lines.length; i++, line = lines[i]) {
     console.log(line); //Outputs "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"
}
```

In that case case 1 prints

```
line 1
line 1
line 2
```

And case 2 prints

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

As for why, `i++` means

```
temp = i;
i = i + 1;
return temp;
```

so in the first case if i = 0 this part

```
line = lines[i++]
```

will be this

```
line = lines[0], i = i + 1
```

since `temp` in the example of what `i++` actually means is `0` at the point it's used.

whereas in the second case

```
i++, line = lines[i]
```

You're doing the postincrement before it's used

To be clear `i++` this is called post incrementing. The value of the expression is the value **before it was incremented**.

If you actually mean *increment* instead of *postincrement* use `++i`

As for elegant, that's an opinion. It's not clear what you're trying to do and there are certainly reasons to use loops based on indices but just in case here's a few other ways to iterate

```js
var lines = ["Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3"];

// use a function
lines.forEach(function(line) {
   console.log(line);
});

// use a function with arrow syntax
lines.forEach(line => {
   console.log(line);
});

// and of course if you really want to use indices why is
// this not elegant?
for (let i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; ++i) {
  const line = lines[i];
  console.log(line);
}
```

It's not clear to me why you think you're solution is elegant. I'd look at your solution and think it's obfusticated. In other words it's hard to understand and hard to understand is not elegant.

Comment: `for (line = lines[i]; i < lines.length; line = lines[++i]) {` would work as required

Comment: Yes, of course, which is why I explained `++i` vs `i++` and hoped that would be obvious

Comment: I must've missed that in the answer

Comment: Good point. I expect people to follow the logic. if I explain that `i++` is returning 0 and why that's the cause of a bug and then I explain that `++i` will return the incremented value I expect them to connect dots. My bad.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that first part should be `line = lines[i];`. And the i++ vs ++i makes total sense now. And I shouldn't have realized that. As for the reason behind it...in this case I need to skip ahead in the array and continue running more code. So I can use `line = lines[++i]` inside the loop to advance the line without looping around. forEach can't do this. Besides, forEach is quite slow. Thanks to gman for your detailed explanation and everyone else who chimed in.

Answer (score 0):

> Javascript For Final Expression does not allow complex statements. Why?

You answered your own question. The *final-expression* is an **expression**, not a statement. That is the way the language was designed. It goes back to the comma operator in C forty years ago, if not further.

If you want to assign `line` inside the `for`, you can write your loop this way:

```js
const lines = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0, line; line = lines[i], i < lines.length; i++) {
  console.log(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use two sides.

```
const lines = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0, line = lines[i]; i < lines.length; i++, line = lines[i]) {
    console.log(i, line)
}
```

Or

```
const lines = [1, 2, 3];

for (const [i, line] of lines.entries()) {
    console.log(i, line)
}
```

In terms of performance both are similar. But the second choice use more memory.